# Verifying and reducing Latin squares with Python 3

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, sudoku

Similar to my previous post, I'm completing [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/6v29zk/170821_challenge_328_easy_latin_squares/) challenge, which is to verify whether an *n* × *n* grid is a [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/Latin_square). I have also solved the bonus problem, which is to rearrange a valid Latin square so that its first row and first column are in order.

It is intended that both functions could be used independently. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
from itertools import chain

def is_latin(n, numbers):
    assert type(numbers) is str
    assert type(n) is str or type(n) is int

    n = int(n)
    list_numbers = [int(m) for m in numbers.split(" ")]

    valid_combination = set(range(1, n+1))
    rows = (set(list_numbers[m:m + n]) for m in range(0, n ** 2, n))
    columns = (set(list_numbers[m::n]) for m in range(n))

    for line in chain(rows, columns):
        if not(line == valid_combination):
            return False
        elif line == valid_combination:
            continue
        else:
            raise Exception("{}{}".format(line, valid_combination))
    return True

def reduce_latin(n, numbers):
    assert type(numbers) is str
    assert type(n) is str or type(n) is int

    n = int(n)
    latin = is_latin(n, numbers)
    if latin:
        return [[((i+m)%n)+1 for i in range(n)] for m in range(n)]
    elif not latin:
        return None
    else:
        raise Exception("{}{}".format(latin, numbers))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(reduce_latin("5", "1 2 3 4 5 5 1 2 3 4 4 5 1 2 3 3 4 5 1 2 2 3 4 5 1"))
```

Comment: Please note the [site standards](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993/9357) when posting [tag:programming-challenge] questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can make few minor improvements like:-

- For comparing types use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead of comparing types using `is`. `is` won't work in case of multiple-inheritance. Plus for comparing against multiple types you can do `isinstance(n, (str, int))`. Read: [Differences between `isinstance()` and `type()` in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/846892)
- The `elif` and `else` block in `is_latin` function look redundant to me, you only need to check for mismatch there. Plus `if line != valid_combination` is more readable than: `if not(line == valid_combination)`.
- The `else` block in `reduce_latin` is also unreachable and you can remove it too.
- Your code has couple of PEP 8 errors that you could check here: http://pep8online.com/

Answer (score 1):

Duck typing is the norm in Python.  I consider your assertions to be distracting.  If you want strict typing, use [type annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) with [some enforcement mechanism](https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce) or static analysis.

The challenge merely states that the array should contain "*n* different symbols", and that the input consists of numbers.  You have assumed that those symbols must be {1, 2, 3, …, *n*}.

In this code…

> ```
> if not(line == valid_combination):
>     return False
> elif line == valid_combination:
>     continue
> else:
>     raise Exception("{}{}".format(line, valid_combination))
> ```

… I don't see the point of the `else` block — either the objects are equal or they are not.  What else could happen?  (In any case, the exception message is rather cryptic.  Also, `not(line == valid_combination)` would be better written as `line != valid_combination`.)

I think that the intentions could be expressed more clearly if you replaced the `for` loop with

```
return all(r == valid_combination for r in rows) and \
       all(c == valid_combination for c in columns)
```

Similarly, it doesn't make sense to have three branches in `reduce_latin()`:

> ```
> if latin:
>     return [[((i+m)%n)+1 for i in range(n)] for m in range(n)]
> elif not latin:
>     return None
> else:
>     raise Exception("{}{}".format(latin, numbers))
> ```

I would just say `if not latin: raise ArgumentError(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

The important issues are pointed out already by @200_success and Ashwini Chaudhary

- unreachable code
- wrong testing for type
- importing chain for no reason
- assertions not pythonic

Still there are some points left.

---

The challenge requires lowercase output, use something like

```
print("true" if is_latin(...) else "false")
```

or

```
print(str(is_latin(...)).lower())
```

---

Your assertions are not necessary as you call the functions yourself. if any you cold assert that the input is a valid square

```
assert n**2 == len(list_numbers)
```

---

Your tests for validity (for siplicity i stick to symbols 1 .. n)

```
line == valid_combination
```

are hard to read. for readability it is usually better to provide a predicate like

```
def is_valid(n, l):
    return set(l) == set(range(1, n+1))
```

if you hold your rows and columns as list of lists (which has some other advantages we will see later) you can even omit parameter n whe testing a line

```
def is_valid(l):
    return set(l) == set(range(1, len(l)+1))
```

---

I think you got the optional part wrong. the task is to reduce the given square, not to construct one from scratch. This requires you to hold the square in a representation allowing you to shuffle columns and rows. a set does not keep the order, i suggest a simple list of lists. the challenge requires sorting the first row and the first column, very similar tasks that can be done by the same sorting function if we transpose the matrix. so i suggest to start with a list of rows

```
rows = [list_numbers[i:i+n] for i in range(0, n ** 2, n)]
```

and provide a transpose function

```
def transpose(m):
    return [[r[i] for r in m] for i in range(len(m[0]))]
```

which we use to get columns

```
columns = transpose(rows)
```

now we check for

```
all(is_valid(l) for l in rows) and all(is_valid(l) for l in columns)
```

which is more readable than chain, as we want to join the results rather than the input data.

---

We also have all we need to do the reduce

```
rows = sorted(rows)
columns = sorted(transpose(rows))
rows = transpose(columns)
```